# How to measure the practicality of a market portfolio for long-term investment?

Tags: equities, portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization

Do you believe that the composition of the market portfolio that you have found is a desirable or practical one as an investment?

Explain why or why not, based on the positions of your stocks.

I have 30 stocks that I'm analysing and found the market portfolio (tangency portfolio) to have these statistics: `Mean=0.03972`, `S.d=0.0568`.

How would I know if the market portfolio is desirable or practical? What should I be looking for exactly?

Answer (score 1):

There are many things to consider but if my assumption is correct that this question is asked as part of some class I’d mention the following two aspects first:

- The risk-return or Sharpe ratio of this portfolio compared to alternative investments
- The weights of the portfolio. What would it imply if some of them are significantly smaller than zero or larger than one?