# Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, sharpe-ratio, bond-portfolio

Conceptually, what are the drawbacks / unforeseen risks of running a portfolio whose weight are derived from what would have maximised the sharpe ratio over the previous time period (last 30 days) ?

Comment: This is quite broad but does this help: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/43695/848 ?

Comment: How well can you estimate expected returns and covariance using 30 days of data?

Comment: Good question Matthew Gunn. I want my statistics to respond to current observed market moves. I arbitrarily picked 30 days. I am afraid that if I go for a longer data set, what I will capture is event that happened in the past and are less likely to influence current market condition.

What should I use instead, knowing I want to keep things simple for now ?

Comment: Expected returns estimated as actual returns over the last 30 days are likely to be almost worthless as a predictor. No better than random numbers. You may want to think of other ways of coming up with expected returns.

Comment: Here is a paper in which short lookback windows (up to 12 months) are used to construct tangency (max Sharpe ratio) portfolios. In essence, this is a momentum-based investment strategy. The backtest results presented in the paper are fairly encouraging. https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2606884